# SQL/Database Design Subtype or Attributes more suitable?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am a student taking my first SQL Class. I have attached below the design of my RDBMS. I'm quite confused on where to go from here for the following requirements:

I need to be able to track:
Whether an Entree is Hot/Cold
A Main is Small or Large sized and whether its Vegetarian or Gluten Free
Lastly whether the desserts are lactose free.

My understanding tells me I could create more sub-types for the individual categories to complete this though I'm unsure whether just having attributes would be a better way to complete this task. (eg. Main has sub-types that are Partial and overlapping for Small, large, vegetarian, gluten free)

[image: Design]

Thanks, help is appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Your database design should reflect the relationship nature of your data.

The very basic idea:

- 1-n relationship, and you have a ForeignKey.
- n-m relationship, and you have a Junction Table.
- 1-1 relationship, and a new field should be enough.

Due to the information provided, an entree being Cold/Hot, a main Small/Large and desserts Blue/Green, fields are enough.

You may still create other tables to store the possible value of each field, if you feel it's necessary for some reason, but fields only are fine design in most cases.

I suggest you google around for database design, you'll find more information than this small post :)